# Git pull gives 'Already up-to-date' after committing

Tags: git, github, push, gitlab, git-pull

I am working on a something where I use two different VM's. On the first one, I create a file that I add, commit and push to the repository. Later, I clone the repository on the other VM. Then I go back to the first VM to do some changes in the file to add and commit the changes to then pull on the second VM. The problem is that I don't get the changes that are done, it says: `Already up-to-date.`

On the clone VM, `git log` outputs:

```
root@master:/home/test/hello/learning# git log
commit 1f15a20164b57303d1cc8bb8f518b4560ad44ad9
Author: test <test@stud.cn.no>
Date:   Tue Jan 13 14:30:33 2015 +0000

    2nd

commit 77950eb49e28aadd49ddb78b9a48701c4ecb910a
Author: test <test@stud.cn.no>
Date:   Tue Jan 13 14:27:53 2015 +0000

    Forste
```

On the VM where I created the repository, `git log` gives:

```
root@python:/home/ubuntu/learning# git log
commit 89fead2b83d16373723d06954a0f4f29a695d6f4
Author: test <test@stud.cn.no>
Date:   Tue Jan 13 14:34:31 2015 +0000

    NA

commit 1f15a20164b57303d1cc8bb8f518b4560ad44ad9
Author: test <test@stud.cn.no>
Date:   Tue Jan 13 14:30:33 2015 +0000

    2nd

commit 77950eb49e28aadd49ddb78b9a48701c4ecb910a
Author: test <test@stud.cn.no>
Date:   Tue Jan 13 14:27:53 2015 +0000

    Forste
```

And `git status` gives:

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to `push` your new commit, which the output of `git status` is actually telling you:

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.  <--- Right here
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Remember that Git is distributed. Almost anything you do only exists on your local machine until you explicitly share it, usually by running something like `git push` or `git push origin master`.

Comment: I am working on a task where it say that I only is going to commit and pull to see the change I have made. Here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pgobx74mtqrgo9l/pp.png?dl=0

Comment: @user3270211, it depends on how your remotes are configured. Based on your question it sounds like you've got two VMs and a remote (e.g. GitHub or Bitbucket). That's *three* repositories. The directions you linked to in your comment suggest that one of your VMs should be a remote of the other; you would `push` and `fetch` / `pull` directly to the VM without going through a third shared remote.

Comment: Right, I have misunderstood the task. The push and pull should be between those VMs (Sincce you make on of them to a server) and not through Github or Bitbucket. Thanks for clearing it up for me.